# CountDown Timer with Transparent textview in center of the Game screen

Tags: java, android, ios, timer, countdowntimer

I am developing a game. In my game i have a dialog to close and resume the game.The thing which i want is when i press the "NO" button of dialog then start counting 3 to 0 and then resume the game.
Please tell me how to Implement CountDown Timer with transparent textview in center of the game screen and after 3 seconds timer invisible as well.
please solve my problem by editing my code.
Here's my code of AlertDialog

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {


    GamePanel.thread.setRunning(false);
    // in the next line of code we also style the dialog through xml which i put in styles
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,R.style.myBackgroundStyle).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Exit Alert");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Do you really want to exit the Game?");
    alertDialog.setButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //Best way is firstly use finish() and after that use System.exit(0) to clear static variables. It will give you some free space.
            // A lot of applications leave working processes and variables what makes me angry. After 30 minutes of using memory is full and i have to run Task Manager - Lvl 2 clear memory
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
            return;

        } });
    alertDialog.setButton2("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();




            GamePanel.thread.setRunning(true);
            return;
        }});
    alertDialog.show();

    return true;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);}
```

Any help would be appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    final TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(tv, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,true);

    popupWindow.showAtLocation(getCurrentFocus(), Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
    new AsyncTask<Void,Integer,Void>(){
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            int inc = 3 ;
            while(true){
                publishProgress(inc);
                inc -- ;
                if(inc == 0 ){
                    break;
                }
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            popupWindow.dismiss();
            GamePanel.thread.setRunning(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            tv.setText(values[0]+"");

        }
    }.execute();
```

How about this code in you button2 onclicklistener? This a idea, may be has a bug. Hope can help you.

Comment: when i press my "NO" button Game is stuck and not responding.

Comment: Does the popupwindow show?  If you don't use the asynctask，is Game responding？

Comment: No there is no popupwindow. when i press "NO" button of Dialog my game is just stopped and not responding. if you have any idea about my problem please edit my code thanks.